# How to add addional 0 to select_month option in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, select

heres the code

```
<%= select_month nil, {use_two_digit_numbers: true}, {:name => 'expMonth', class: "form-control" } %>
```

and the results

```
<select class="form-control" id="date_month" name="expMonth">
    <option value="1">01</option>
    <option value="2">02</option>
    <option value="3">03</option>
    <option value="4">04</option>
    <option value="5">05</option>
    <option value="6">06</option>
    <option value="7">07</option>
    <option value="8">08</option>
    <option value="9">09</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="11">11</option>
    <option value="12">12</option>
</select>
```

if you can see the value of the options has no "0" i want to add 0 like 01, 02 and soon except 10 to 12 which already a double digit. see example below

```
<select class="form-control" id="date_month" name="expMonth">
    <option value="01">01</option>
    <option value="02">02</option>
    <option value="03">03</option>
    <option value="04">04</option>
    <option value="05">05</option>
    <option value="06">06</option>
    <option value="07">07</option>
    <option value="08">08</option>
    <option value="09">09</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="11">11</option>
    <option value="12">12</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: By the way, this is the implementation for `use_two_digit_numbers`: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/597fa0b42f90bbef6a8c7628d4e08fb132fba887/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/date_helper.rb#L915-L916 ---- If you really do need a two digit value, you could easily implement this yourself, wherever it gets used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say you're better off with using something like

`select_tag 'date_month', options_for_select((1..12).collect{ |i| "%02d" % i })`

Comment: Or just `options_for_select("01".."12")`.